Drawing an ellipse from its equation
I want to draw the ellipse whose formula is x^2+19xy+4y^2-45y-1=0 using TikZ-pgf. I suppose that I could write a program to compute lots of points on the ellipse, but I am hoping that there is a way to draw a smooth curve directly.

Are you sure that the equation is an ellipse?

2 general approaches: A) solve for y, draw as y(x) (you can also draw formulas). B) substitute x=r(phi) cos(phi), y= r(phi) sin(phi), solve quadratic equation in r, plot r(phi). // You can set how many points pgfplots will use for calculations. But you can't provide an implicit equation: solve it first.

Using Geogebra online exporting in TikZ you obtain an hyperbola and not an ellipse:
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round,line join=round,>=triangle 45,x=1cm,y=1cm]
\begin{axis}[
    x=1cm,y=1cm,
    axis lines=middle,
    ymajorgrids=true,
    xmajorgrids=true,
    xmin=-4, xmax=6,
    ymin=-4, ymax=4,
    ]
\clip(-14,-9) rectangle (13,8);
\draw [samples=50, color= red, domain=-0.99:0.99, rotate around={-40.51:(2.48,-0.26)}, xshift=2.48cm, yshift=-0.26cm, line width=1pt] 
    plot ({0.827*(1+(\x)^2)/(1-(\x)^2)},{0.634*2*(\x)/(1-(\x)^2)});
\draw [samples=50, color= red, domain=-0.99:0.99, rotate around={-40.51:(2.48,-0.26)}, xshift=2.48cm, yshift=-0.26cm, line width=1pt] 
    plot ({0.827*(-1-(\x)^2)/(1-(\x)^2)},{0.634*(-2)*(\x)/(1-(\x)^2)});
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



I was guessing that it was an ellipse! I actually tried using Geogebra but from lack of enough experience I didn't enter the equation correctly.

+1. It's a bit of a pity that Geogebra is still using the (long deprecated) arrows library...

@Rmano Thank you very much for your kindness. You have right on the arrows.
